# ¿Cómo podría implementar git en Prestashop?

Tags: git, prestashop

Estoy intentando buscar por Internet alguna manera de gestionar el control de versiones en Prestashop, pero no encuentro nada. Si se pudiera subir el repositorio a bitbucket mucho mejor. Alguien tendría alguna solución?

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta literal a tu pregunta: **¿Cómo podría implementar git en Prestashop?** es muy sencilla:

Aprender que es y como utilitzar git...

Que tendra q ver prestashop en instalar algo en bitbucket??

Aqui explica explica facilmente los primeros pasos

[primer repositorio en bitbucket](http://aprendegit.com/creando-nuestro-primer-repositorio-en-bitbucket-parte-i-registro-y-creacion-del-repositorio/)

Suerte!!